# Django : profile edition set_password()

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I would like to create an API for a mobile application. In this application, we can create an account, and of course, edit our profile.
For create an account, I use the django account default model like that:
*models.py*:

```
    def create_user(self, email, username, phone, deliveryAddress, postalCode, city, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a phone number')
        if not deliveryAddress:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a delivery Address')
        if not postalCode:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a postal code")
        if not city:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a city')

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            phone = phone,
            deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress,
            postalCode = postalCode,
            city = city,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, phone, deliveryAddress, postalCode, city, password=None):

        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            password = password,
            phone = phone,
            deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress,
            postalCode = postalCode,
            city = city,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using = self._db)

class memberArea(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone = models.TextField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    deliveryAddress = models.TextField()
    postalCode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    forget = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'phone', 'deliveryAddress', 'postalCode', 'city']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email + ' : ' + self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

When I create an account, I automaticaly encrypt the user password with **set_password()**
Now, I want to make a view to edit an account.
Of course I want the password to be encrypted too.
This is my code:
*serializer.py*:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = memberArea
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'deliveryAddress', 'postalCode', 'city']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
```

*views.py*:

```
#Edit account
@api_view(['PUT', ])
def edit_account(request, pk):
    try:
        account = memberArea.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except memberArea.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = AccountSerializer(account, data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'Account updated with success !'
            return Response(data)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

I don't know where and how I can encrypt the password before updating the profile.
Maybe I can do that in my serializer file by finding the account that we want to edit but I don't know how to do that in this file...
Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do [Field-level validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) in your serializer to encrypt the raw password to a hashed one.

Here is an example of encrypting the raw password in your AccountSerializer. Then, every raw password from a request's json payload will be encrypted to a hashed one.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = memberArea
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'deliveryAddress', 'postalCode', 'city']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }

    def validate_password(self, raw_password):
        return make_password(raw_password)
```

Comment: I tried to add your code in mine, but when I run my code, the password changed but still not encrypted

Comment: What do you mean by "password changed but not encrypted"? Could you give an example?

Comment: For exemple, if my password is 'azerty', in the database, I will be able to see the password as 'azerty'

Comment: Note: Encryption is the method by which information is converted into secret code that hides the information's true meaning.  
With encryption, you cannot see a user's raw password in the database. Rather, the hashed value(secret code of raw password) will be stored.

Comment: Okay I understand better. But I don't know why, but when I create a user (and also when I edit his profile), the password is save in the database. But for me, I don't ask for a password in my model...

Comment: As you are using AbstractBaseUser to create your own user model(memberArea), it thus contains all django's User fields and its model manager. Check fields of Django User model out here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model

Comment: Thanks I'm going to check your link. But with AbstractBaseUser is it a simple way to edit my profile (and my password)?

Comment: Yeah, sure. It contains many useful functions and fields and saves your time to reinvent the wheel.